# Get Facebook objects information with C#

Tags: c#, facebook, winforms, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm new to facebook development. I'm using C# on Windows Form and I'm searching for a way to get information about a post on facebook.

I've read documentation and see that I can use FQL to query facebook object.

My questions:

1. is using FQL it a good way in WindowsForm solutions ?
2. I need to get the count on how many 'like' are done on an object (link or photo). Can I do this with like Table ?
3. I need to know who is sharing my facebook objects (link or photo). Where is the relative Table I can use ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't had a lot of luck with FQL and prefer to use the  [graph api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api)

Using this in combination with the facebook SDK dll you can quickly retrieve information about a post as a json object using the following code.

```
  var client = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
  var jsonPost = (JsonObject) client.Get(postId);
```

As for seeing who has shared your objects I'm not sure if that can be done using the graphAPI, you would be able to see likes and comments of a object by using

```
  var client = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
  var jsonLikes = (JsonObject) client.Get(postId + "/likes");
  var jsonComents = (JsonObject) client.Get(postId + "/comments");
```

Comment: Your welcome, facebook have a great little tool for testing the graph api, give it a go. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer